# How to see why "snapd.refresh.service" failed to start on startup?

Tags: systemd, debugging, logs

After upgrading to `snapd` version `2.0.8` I have noticed that I get an error message about `snapd.refresh.service` failing to start on startup, the error tells me which command to run in order to see why it is failing, however the message disappears so quickly that I can't see what that command is.

I understand that this is probably a bug, and I plan to report it as such, however I was wondering if anybody had any idea of the command it could have been? I think it might have been a `systemd` command but I'm not entirely sure. Is there somewhere where the message would have been logged (I have already tried syslog and `dmesg` but it is not there)?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

---

For anyone who is interested there is already a report filed on the matter [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `systemctl status` to look at the tail of the logs, plus any other information that systemd has about that service:

```
systemctl status snapd.refresh.service
```

For example:

```
$ systemctl status lightdm.service   
● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/lightdm.service.d
           └─override.conf
        /lib/systemd/system/display-manager.service.d
           └─xdiagnose.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-06-12 09:27:09 IST; 2 days ago
     Docs: man:lightdm(1)
 Main PID: 2218 (lightdm)
   CGroup: /system.slice/lightdm.service
           ├─2218 /usr/sbin/lightdm
           └─2245 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch

Jun 12 09:27:12 host lightdm[2278]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jun 12 09:27:12 host lightdm[2278]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Jun 12 09:27:13 host lightdm[2278]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Jun 12 09:27:28 host lightdm[2490]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jun 12 09:27:28 host lightdm[2490]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Jun 12 09:27:28 host lightdm[2490]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jun 12 09:27:28 host lightdm[2490]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Jun 12 09:27:28 host lightdm[2490]: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "muru"
Jun 12 09:27:36 host lightdm[2490]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user muru by (uid=0)
Jun 15 05:53:19 host systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/lightdm.service.d/override.conf:2] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: true
```

Information of note:

- state of the service (enabled/disabled) as well as the state set by the vendor (package, in this case)
- location of service file, plus locations of any overriding files (the "Drop-In" files)
- PID, cgroup and child processes

Comment: Yes, I just found that to be what it tells me to run at startup.

Answer (score 2):

To show systemd logs for the `snapd.refresh.service` unit, use:

```
journalctl -u snapd.refresh.service
```